# If I have a json string how do I calculate the number of bytes needed when stored?

Tags: java, json, storage, character-encoding, byte

I have a json string formatted displayed in a web page. What I am trying to understand is what is the size in terms of bytes that this json string requires.
If I copy and pipe to `wc -c` I get `1000` which is the number of characters but I don't think that this means that the json string is 1000 bytes as I have seen googling around as a suggestion.
The reason I am confused is the following:
In java for instance a `String` is composed of `char` and each char is 2 bytes to support utf-8. Json also supports utf-8 so I am not sure if I should consider that the size of the json string requires 2000 bytes or what is a way to figure this out?

Comment: the question is what is the source string, and what is the encoding of the storage.   if it is english alphabet utf-8 encoding will be 1 byte per char, but if you have other languages, emoji, etc in the string then it could be more than one byte per char.    storage the question is what encoding.  for java take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Java internally uses UTF-16 where characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF (excluding U+D800..U+DFFF which are not characters) are encoded on 16 bits (2 bytes) each and all the other ones (from U+10000 to U+10FFFF) on 32 bits (2 16-bit nibbles, 4 bytes).

A JSON string is generally encoded in UTF-8 (as per newer versions of [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), that's even [required for interchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8.1)).

UTF-8 encodes characters on 1 to 4 bytes depending on the characters. Specifically, all the characters in `String` are encoded on 1 byte each.

There are obviously `"` (single-byte) characters surrounding a JSON string which add 2 bytes, and [characters can be escaped](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7).

For instance, the  single character (U+1F9D9 in Unicode) is encoded as 0xd83e 0xddd9 in UTF-16 (4 bytes), as 0xf0 0x9f 0xa7 0x99 in UTF-8 (also 4 bytes). A JSON representation of a string made of just one of that character can be either `""` encoded in UTF-8 which is 2+4 = 6 bytes, or `"\ud83e\uddd9"` (with variations possible in the case of the hex digits) so 14 single-byte characters so 14 bytes.

To measure a size in number of bytes, you can use `wc -c`. You need `wc -m` to measure the size in characters.

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
```

:conveniently, my locale does use the UTF-8 encoding so `wc -m` will be able to decode a UTF-8-encoded  and report it as being one character:

```
$ printf %s '""' | wc -m -c
      3       6
```

3 characters, 6 bytes.

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | wc -m -c
     14      14
```

14 characters, 14 bytes.

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9" ""' | jq -r .
```

`jq`, a JSON processor does recognise both JSON strings as representations of a string made of one  character.

If you want to know how many characters there are in the string that the `"\ud83e\udDd9"` JSON string represents, you can do:

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | wc -m
1
```

Or let `jq` compute the length:

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq length
1
```

And for the number of bytes in the UTF-8 encoding of that string:

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | wc -c
4
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq utf8bytelength
4
```

For the number of bytes in other encodings of that string, pipe to `iconv -f utf-8 -t other-encoding` before piping to `wc -c`:

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le | wc -c
4
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 | wc -c
6
```

(includes a 2-byte byte-order-mark character)

```
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | iconv -f utf-8 -t gb18030 | wc -c
4
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4 | wc -c
4
$ printf %s '"\ud83e\udDd9"' | jq -j . | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-32 | wc -c
8
```

(also includes a BOM, this time encoded on 4 bytes).